# Google autocomplete place api i want to set specific state that sate get only city

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to set specific state in google auto complete place api. which state  i specify only that state of city or area i want to get in response. i.e
i specify gujrat in state so get only location of gujrat only . can help me out.

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyCz2s4KgGmojRTMLwIFlqmBA43_qlQDx4w&components=country:in&types=(cities)&input=dg

Comment: We also search for it and i was found in one site and it's also working for me
link - http://laravelcode.com/post/auto-complete-city-google-map-api-in-laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
function initialize() {

     var options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
     };

     var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }
```

you can use bound:

```
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(sw_latitude, sw_longitude ); //South West Lat Lng
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(ne_latitude, ne_longitude ); //North East Lat Lng
var gujaratBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast );

var options = {
    bounds: gujaratBounds,
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'in' }
};
```

for more,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: Thanks i am using in android how to use bounds

Comment: @MehulTank , follow this 

https://jsfiddle.net/c5yp0owr/

and from this you can find the Bound values:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.2587,71.1924&sensor=false